Convergence criterion for integral Neumann series
I know that if I have a Neumann series
$$
\sum_{j=0}^{\infty}A^j
$$
then it converges as long as $\rho(A)<1$. For a Neumann series in integral form, considering a $t$ dependent square matrix $A(t)$
$$
I + \int_{t_0}^{t}\mathrm{d}\xi_1A(\xi_1) + \int_{t_0}^{t}\mathrm{d}\xi_1\int_{t_0}^{\xi_1}\mathrm{d}\xi_2A(\xi_1)A(\xi_2) + \cdots
$$
I know it will converge up to a certain $t$ if $\int_{t_0}^{t}\mathrm{d}\xi\rvert\rvert A(\xi)\rvert\rvert < \infty$, where here I use the spectral norm.
But I can't seem to understand this convergence criterion. Intuitively I would imagine that if $\int_{t_0}^{t}\mathrm{d}\xi\rvert\rvert A(\xi)\rvert\rvert$ yelds a sufficiently large value then the series would not converge. So, why does this criterion work?
Any help is appreciated.

My guess it that you have to use that $\int^t_{t_0} \int^{\xi_1}{t_0} \int^{\xi_2}{t_0} ... \int^{\xi_n}_{t_0} 1~\mathrm{d}\xi_n ...~\mathrm{d}\xi_1  = \tfrac{(t-t0)^{n+1}}{(n+1)!}$, so the more integrals you have, the more it "contracts" and at some point you shold be smaller than $1$. So the trick is not to brutally estimate the integral but to compute it (after you estimated $A$).
